When i try to launch chrome, i get this message error. How do i solve it? Obs.: victor-Aspire-A515-54G is the old pc name, the new is host
victor@host:~$ google-chrome-stable

[4391:4391:0502/105509.491234:ERROR:process_singleton_posix.cc(353)]
The profile appears to be in use by another Google Chrome process
(9965) on another computer (victor-Aspire-A515-54G). Chrome has locked
the profile so that it cannot be corrupted. If you are sure that no
other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and
restart Chrome.
[4391:4391:0502/105509.491303:ERROR:message_box_dialog.cc(146)] Unable
to show a dialog outside the UI thread message loop: Google Chrome -
The profile appears to be in use by another Google Chrome process
(9965) on another computer (victor-Aspire-A515-54G). Chrome has locked
the profile so that it cannot be corrupted. If you are sure that no
other processes are using this profile, you can unlock the profile and
restart Chrome.


This is a chrome issue, not an ubuntu issue. Suggest you purge chrome from your system and re-install. You need to determine the name and type of the chrome package; a deb, snap, flatpak?  Then you use apt, snap, or flatpak to purge and re-install. Be sure to purge, not delete or remove. Purge will remove the config, which is your problem, and enable a fresh install.
